# Social Engine display user photo in I4US widget

Tags: php, socialengine

I'm using I4USPHP widget for some PHP code, and everything works fine - until the moment that I need to display some user photo. I have an array of users, and have also their IDs. I called this function, but it definitely doesn't work:

```
echo $this->itemPhoto($someUser['user_id'], 'thumb.icon');
```

After a while i tought that `$this` keyword is creating problem, then I tried following:

```
echo Engine_Api::_()->itemPhoto($korisnik['user_id'], 'thumb.icon');
```

but still not working. Does someone have a clue what I've been doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing first argument user_id. This function require first argument is "item object" that's why its not working

Controller : `$this->view->subject = Engine_Api::_()->core()->getSubject('event');`

View  : `<?php echo $this->itemPhoto($this->subject(), 'thumb.icon') ?>`